# Glueing functions, underdetermined PDE

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Suppose that $U\subset\subset V$, where $U, V$ are open bounded Lipschitz domains in $\mathbb{R}^d$, $d\geq 1$. Let $u\in X(U):=\{ f\in L^1(U;\mathbb{R}^d): \ \nabla f\in M(U;\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}), \ \mathrm{div} f\in L^2(U) \}$ and let $v\in X(V\setminus\overline{U})$. Here $\nabla f\in M(U;\mathbb{R}^{d\times d})$ means that the distributional gradient can be represented by a finite Radon measure.

The problem is to define a function $w$, such that $w\in X(V)$ and $w|_{U}=u$ and $w|_{V\setminus\overline{U}}=v$. Obviously the function $w=u\chi_U+v\chi_{V\setminus\overline{U}}$ won't do, since the divergence condition in the definition of space $X$ is not satisfied unless traces of $u$ and $v$ in the normal direction to the boundary $\partial U$ agree.

My approach is the following. I define an interface layer $I_\varepsilon$ of thickness $2\varepsilon$ around the boundary $\partial U$ ( $I_\varepsilon\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ open) and sets 
$$U_\varepsilon:= U\setminus \overline{I_\varepsilon}, \quad V_\varepsilon:=V\setminus\overline{U_\varepsilon\cup I_\varepsilon}.$$
Then, since $u\in X(U)$ and $v\in X(V\setminus\overline{U})$, in particular $u\in X(U_\varepsilon)$ and $v\in X(V_\varepsilon)$, so the only missing ingredient is a function $w_\varepsilon$ on the interface layer, such that the following underdetermined BVP
$$ \mathrm{div}w_\varepsilon=f \quad \text{in } I_\varepsilon, \\ w_\varepsilon|_{\partial I_\varepsilon\cap U}=u, \quad w_\varepsilon|_{\partial I_\varepsilon\cap (V\setminus\overline{U})}=v  $$
is satisfied for (at least) $f\in L^2(I_\varepsilon)$.

I'm curious if there is an existence theory of such PDE and if so, a reference would be greatly appreciated. Also, a better gluing ideas are more than welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: If $w|_U=u$ and $w_{V\backslash \bar U}=v$, doesn't that imply $w=u\chi_U+\chi_{V\backslash \bar U}$?

Comment: @MichaelRenardy It does, but this new function $w$ must belong to $X(V)$ as well. The divergence may have jump on the boundary, which violates the requirement that $divw\in L^2$, unless traces of $u$ and $v$ agree.

Comment: I do not understand, sorry. The only freedom in the choice of $w$ are its values along $\partial U$?

Comment: @PieroD'Ancona Yes, but combining functions $u$ and $v$ with characteristic functions generates a jump along $\partial U$.

Comment: The jump is generated by the values of $u,v$, not by the characteristic functions

Comment: @PieroD'Ancona Obviously, that is what I had in mind.